# Import Module whereas function is expected in Python

Tags: python, function, module

I've created a package 'package' with an `__init__` file in which I do the following import:

```
from .name import name
```

When I check in debugging mode it does indeed import the correct function.

In another piece of my code I do the following:

```
from package import name
```

Then I get *TypeError: 'module' object is not callable* when calling `name`. I expect the function `name`, but it obtains the module `name`. I know I can solve this by typing `from package.name import name`. But I expected this code to work, what goes wrong? It seems that it works on other functions.

Comment: The file should not have the same name as the function, that's it

Comment: @Gugu72 That shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @mkrieger1 It's still pretty bad practice

Comment: OP, could you include the file structure of your package and the `__init__.py` files?

Comment: @Gugu72 I just found out that the `from package import name` is within the same package. That's probably why it's not working?